# Why does media9 need babel?

Tags: babel, polyglossia, movie15, media9

I wonder why the `media9` package, a new replacement for `movie15`, needs `babel`? And what will happen if I would want to load `polyglossia` instead of `babel` as it is required for XeLaTeX to compile Russian text (note that standard babel conflicts with XeLaTeX if Russian language is requested)?

NB: Fortunately, there is a custom russification for babel (http://ctan.org/pkg/russian) which does not conflict with XeLaTeX--I am just curious.

Comment: The package uses `\defineshorthand`; I believe it can easily dispense with it.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, media9 uses `\defineshorthand`. Could we replace it with something home-made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `media9`, the command `\defineshorthand`, defined in `babel`, is used in order to correctly treat possibly active characters that may occur in URLs and path specifications passed to `\includemedia`.

Some characters frequently encountered in URLs, such as `:` and `~` have a special meaning in a standard LaTeX environment or get the same, if a certain language package is loaded with `babel`. However, URLs and paths containing such characters must be inserted verbatim into certain PDF objects related to media inclusion.

As an example, one of the characters `\usepackage[french]{babel}` makes active is `:`. In file `frenchb.ldf`, `:` is redefined as

```
\initiate@active@char{:}%
\declare@shorthand{french}{:}{%
      \ifhmode
        \ifdim\lastskip>\z@
          \unskip\penalty\@M\Fcolonspace
        \else
          \FDP@colonspace
        \fi
      \fi
      \string:}
```

In order to prevent `\includemedia` from inserting rubbish into the PDF, it temporarily redefines it as a simple letter:

```
\defineshorthand{:}{\detokenize{:}}
```

which is undone, as soon as command `\includemedia` has completed.

I am not happy with `media9` depending on `babel`. I prefer a stand-alone solution. Maybe someone capable can help?

Comment: Formal answer to my question as it was formulated is given by Alexander Grahn, so I am going to accept his answer. But I also want the package `media9` to be improved so I am postponing formal approval for not to disturb fruitful discussion.

Comment: Next release (to appear after Easter) won't depend on babel any longer, thanks to @egreg!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `media9` requires `babel` just to have available `\defineshorthand`, which is used in the macro `\mix@uribegin`, which has several lines such as

```
\defineshorthand{"}{\detokenize{"}}%
```

which is meant to say: if `"` is active, redefine it to `\detokenize{"}`. The same effect may be obtained by using a helper macro:

```
\def\neutralize#1{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

and changing the line above into

```
\neutralize{"}
```

If an active `"` is found, it will be changed into a detokenized `"`.

In LaTeX3 parlance this might be

```
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \~
\cs_new:Npn \mix_neutralize_active_char:n #1
  {
   \group_begin:
   \char_set_lccode:nn { `~ }{ `#1 }
   \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \cs_set:Npn ~ }{\token_to_str:N #1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \mix_uribegin:
  {
   \group_begin:
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {"}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {:}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {/}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {?}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {[}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {]}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {@}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {!}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {$}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {&}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {'}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {(}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {)}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {*}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {+}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {,}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {;}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {=}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {-}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {.}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {_}
   \mix_neutralize_active_char:n {~}
   \cs_set:Npn \% {\token_to_str:N \%}
   \cs_set:Npn \# {\token_to_str:N \#}
  }
\group_end:
\cs_set_eq:NN \mix_uriend: \group_end:
```

This should replace the definitions of `\mix@uribegin` and `\mix@uriend`; where these appear, they must be replaced by `\mix_uribegin:` and `\mix_uriend:`

### EDIT

Following Joseph Wright's suggestion, here's a shorter definition:

```
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \~
\cs_new:Npn \mix_uribegin:
  {
   \group_begin:
   \tl_map_inline:nn {":/?[]@!$&'()*+,=-._~}
     {
      \group_begin:
      \char_set_lccode:nn { `\~ }{ `##1 }
      \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \cs_set:Npn ~ }{\token_to_str:N ##1}
     }
   \cs_set:Npn \% {\token_to_str:N \%}
   \cs_set:Npn \# {\token_to_str:N \#}
  }
\group_end:
\cs_set_eq:NN \mix_uriend: \group_end:
```

The principle is exactly the same, but the code is at least more elegant.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. In case of `[french]{babel}`, `:` is translated into `penalty @M  :` in the pdf string. I inserted your LaTeX3 code snippet into `media9.sty`.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn I was expecting that not everything would work immediately. I'll try doing some tests.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn If I define `\NewDocumentCommand{\try}{m}{\mix_uribegin:#1\mix_uriend:}` and then in a French setup I do `\try{?:"}` I get the expected result. I'll complete the code: the `...` stood for "similar lines".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code works almost perfectly. Only `~` still doesn't work. Is it due to its special meaning if ExplSyntaxOn? The error is: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \unhbox
l.30 ]{}{":/?[]@!$&'()*+,;=-._~}

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn I've moved the `\group_end:`, so that in all the definition of `\mix_uribegin:` the `~` is active.

Comment: Wouldn't a mapping make sense here?

Comment: @JosephWright I think so. Another way might be to simply detokenize the argument one needs to sanitize, if macros are not allowed or expected there.

Comment: @egreg: Problem solved! Works perfectly! Thanks a zillion!

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn Waiting for the update on CTAN. :)

Comment: @AlexG The name is *Gregorio*, but don't do a new update only for that. `;-)`